# weighted interval scheduling with two available "workers"

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I'm attempting to write a piece of code that takes in a set of weighted intervals and distribute them optimally between two "workers" maximizing the weight. An example of input would be the following.

```
9
1 2 1
1 3 3
2 4 1
3 5 1
4 6 2
5 7 1
6 8 2
7 9 1
8 10 2
```

"9" is the amount of intervals and the columns are defined as

```
s f v

s=start time
f=finish time
v=weight
```

So far I have used a binary search to determine the "p" value which is the rightmost preceding interval and stored it in an array.  From there I go through the input variables one at a time determining the max weight and whether or not the current interval should be included in either workers "queue" as I will call it.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TABSIZE (100)

int n,s[TABSIZE],f[TABSIZE],v[TABSIZE],p[TABSIZE],M[TABSIZE],M2[TABSIZE];


int binSearchLast(int *a,int n,int key)
{
// Input: int array a[] with n elements in ascending order.
//        int key to find.
// Output: Returns subscript of the last a element <= key.
//         Returns -1 if key<a[0].
// Processing: Binary search.

int low,high,mid;
low=0;
high=n-1;

// subscripts between low and high are in search range.
// size of range halves in each iteration.
// When low>high, low==high+1 and a[high]<=key and a[low]>key.
while (low<=high){
    mid=(low+high)/2;
    if (a[mid]<=key)
        low=mid+1;
    else
        high=mid-1;
}

return high;
}

main()
{
int i,j,sum=0,sum2=0;

scanf("%d",&n);
f[0]=(-999999); // For binarySearchLast
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    scanf("%d %d %d",&s[i],&f[i],&v[i]);
for (i=2;i<=n && f[i-1]<=f[i];i++);
    if (i<=n){
        printf("Intervals not ordered by finish time %d\n",__LINE__);
        exit(0);
    }

for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    p[i]=binSearchLast(f,n+1,s[i]);

M[0]=0;
M2[0]=0;

//checks to see if the resulting weight is bigger in a certain queue
for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
    if(v[i]+M[p[i]]>M[i-1] && !(v[i]+M2[p[i]]>M2[i-1]))
        M[i]=v[i]+M[p[i]];
    else if(v[i]+M2[p[i]]>M2[i-1] && !(v[i]+M[p[i]]>M[i-1]))
        M2[i]=v[i]+M2[p[i]];
    else
        M[i]=M[i-1];
}


printf("\n\nroom 1:\n\n");
for (i=n;i>0; ){
    if (v[i]+M[p[i]]>=M[i-1]){
        printf("%d %d %d\n",s[i],f[i],v[i]);
        sum+=v[i];
        i=p[i];
    }
    else
        i--;
}
printf("\n\nroom 2:\n\n");
for (i=n;i>0; ){
    if (v[i]+M2[p[i]]>=M2[i-1]){
        printf("%d %d %d\n",s[i],f[i],v[i]);
        sum2+=v[i];
        i=p[i];
    }
    else
        i--;
}

printf("sum 1 is %d\n",sum);
printf("sum 2 is %d\n",sum);
}
```

This seems to work for room 1, but room 2 comes out with the exact same queue for some reason.  This is my current output:

```
room 1:

8 10 2
6 8 2
4 6 2
2 4 1
1 2 1

room 2:

8 10 2
6 8 2
4 6 2
2 4 1
1 2 1
```

when the "correct" output should look like:

```
room 1:

8 10 2
6 8 2
4 6 2
2 4 1
1 2 1

room 2:

7 9 1
5 7 1
3 5 1
1 3 3
```

Any insight would be highly appreciated.

EDIT**
Looking at it I'm thinking it might actually have to do with the way I am determining which intervals are included in M[] and M2[] when I print out the result.  It seems it is just a coincidence the output for the two rooms is the same. I still haven't figured out what to do to correct that however, I'm still looking for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** about the requirement ...

When you say you want to "distribute tasks optimally between two workers maximizing the weight", I assume you want to assign tasks to workers such that (a) no worker has overlapping tasks based on start-finish intervals, but (b) the most possible work by weight is actually assigned to workers. If tasks overlap too much it may not be possible to assign all tasks to the two workers because of overlaps. (With your test data, it is possible to assign all the tasks.)

If so, this is a variation of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) but with two knapsacks. This problem is known to be "NP hard" which for practical purpose means it will require a more complex solution than you have coded - no doubt something using recursive programming. However, there are simpler algorithms that yield a good-enough, but generally not optimal, answer.

**Second,** about your solution ...

The central section of your code needs attention. You have:

```
M[0]=0;
M2[0]=0;

//checks to see if the resulting weight is bigger in a certain queue
for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
    if(v[i]+M[p[i]]>M[i-1] && !(v[i]+M2[p[i]]>M2[i-1]))
        M[i]=v[i]+M[p[i]];
    else if(v[i]+M2[p[i]]>M2[i-1] && !(v[i]+M[p[i]]>M[i-1]))
        M2[i]=v[i]+M2[p[i]];
    else
        M[i]=M[i-1];
}
```

I have taken the liberty to expand variable names:

```
// Cumulative weights of tasks assigned to workers 1 and 2.
// E.g., load1[5] is total weight of tasks, selected from
// tasks 1..5, assigned to worker 1.     
load1[0] = 0;
load2[0] = 0;

// checks to see if the resulting weight is bigger in a certain queue
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++){
    if  (weight[i] + load1[prior[i]] > load1[i-1]
    && !(weight[i] + load2[prior[i]] > load2[i-1]))
        load1[i] = weight[i] + load1[prior[i]];
    else
    if  (weight[i] + load2[prior[i]] > load2[i-1]
    && !(weight[i] + load1[prior[i]] > load1[i-1]))
        load2[i] = weight[i] + load2[prior[i]];
    else
        load1[i] = load1[i-1];
}
```

The IF statements cater to only two of four possibilities: `weight[i]` is good in `load1` but not in `load2`, or is good in `load2` but not in `load1`. Your code don't cater to the cases where `weight[i]` is good in both `load1` and `load2`, or good in neither. Also, for each `i`, the code assigns to `load1[i]` or `load2[i]` but not both, so at the end of the loop, half of the array values are undefined.

Because of this, you always go to the default ELSE which fills `load1` with zeroes. At the end of the loop, `load1` is full of zeroes, and `load2` is undefined* (except for `load2[0]`).

Later in the print loops, all the zeroes cause the first print loop to just hops backwards through the `prior` table to print the result you see. Chances are the un-initialized `load2` array also happened to be zeroes, so the second print loop does the same thing.

**What to do?** If you need a guaranteed optimal algorithm, suggest that you look into the Knapsack Problem. If a "good-enough" algorithm will do, perhaps you can experiment with some simple algorithms (e.g., hand out each task to first worker with capacity) and see how they well they run with different test data sets.

(*Technically, because `load2` is implicitly declared `static` in the program, it will be initialized by the C compiler to zeroes, but you should not depend on this.)